# Need to get an Iterable, I've got a List of Dicts

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, flask

Been beating my head against the wall for longer than I care to admit. I have a list of dicts that I need to pass to something as an iterable. I assume I need to take the contents of these dicts and get them into a properly-formatted new dict. I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what my list "contacts" looks like:

```
[{'City': 'Boston',
'Unique_Id': '123456-789',
'FullName': 'Smith, Joe',
'other_id': '0987654',
'area': 'Area 1'},
{'City': 'San Fransisco',
'Unique_Id': '654321-987',
'FullName': 'Brown, John',
'other_id': '7654321',
'area': 'Area 2'},
{'City': 'New York',
'Unique_Id': '7890123-456',
'FullName': 'Incomplete, Guy',
'other_id': None,
'area': None}]
```

I'm trying to pass it to this: https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table

Where the relevant section is:

```
class Item(object):
def __init__(self, name, description):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
...
...
items = [dict(name='Name1', description='Description1'),
     dict(name='Name2', description='Description2'),
     dict(name='Name3', description='Description3')]
```

So I need to get my list "contacts" in some kind of shape to be iterated through by that function, presumably into a new dict. I feel like I need a list comprehension to transform it into a dictionary but I just can't grasp the concept well enough to understand how to do that. I need this to be passed to the function so that it can convert the json list/dict values to an HTML table to output in a little SPA. There's a hard limit of 5 dicts in the list so it shouldn't ever get very long. I assume I want to end up with something like:

```
items = [contacts(name='City', description='Their City'),
 contacts(name='Unique_Id', description='GUID'),
 contacts(name='FullName', description='Name')
...and so on
]
```

I have no idea how though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you *assuming* what you want as a result?  This leaves us guessing what you want.  You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: I'm not. The function expects an iterable. I have a list of dicts that I need to be able to iterate through, in some way that's compatible with the input the flask_table function is expecting. I've copied the template from the function and an example of what I think it should look like. There's not a lot of documentation and I don't have a working example, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Well many people here could easily help you build an iterable if they knew what the result needed to look like.  As an example of tough to answer, what is `contacts`?

Comment: Lists *are* iterables already, so why can't you just pass it to the function?

Comment: re: Paul - I was getting this error, but I think it was related to not defining the cols. 

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to change anything in your dictionary. You just need to update attributes in both classes:

```
# Declare your table
class ItemTable(Table):
    City = Col('City')
    Unique_Id = Col('Unique_Id')
    FullName = Col('FullName')
    other_id = Col("other_id")
    area = Col("area")

# Get some objects
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, City, Unique_Id,FullName,other_id,area):
        self.City = City
        self.Unique_Id = Unique_Id
        self.FullName = FullName
        self.other_id=other_id
        self.area = area
```

and then simply as per from your reference URL:

```
     myTable =   [{'City': 'Boston',
    'Unique_Id': '123456-789',
    'FullName': 'Smith, Joe',
    'other_id': '0987654',
    'area': 'Area 1'},
    {'City': 'San Fransisco',
    'Unique_Id': '654321-987',
    'FullName': 'Brown, John',
    'other_id': '7654321',
    'area': 'Area 2'},
    {'City': 'New York',
    'Unique_Id': '7890123-456',
    'FullName': 'Incomplete, Guy',
    'other_id': None,
    'area': None}]
    table = ItemTable(myTable)
    print(table.__html__())
```

The output is as below:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>City</th><th>Unique_Id</th><th>FullName</th><th>other_id</th><th>area</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Boston</td><td>123456-789</td><td>Smith, Joe</td><td>0987654</td><td>Area 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>San Fransisco</td><td>654321-987</td><td>Brown, John</td><td>7654321</td><td>Area 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>New York</td><td>7890123-456</td><td>Incomplete, Guy</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This makes way more sense, and this is the part I wasn't seeing - defining the cols in addition to the objects is what I was missing in the documentation. Gonna try this now, thank you!

Comment: Glad , it helped.